# Directed graphs

Tags: graphics, diagrams, xfig

I have a problem with the alignment of my diagram, i dont know how make the first two directed graphsto be aligned whith the "=" and aligned with the left brace ( "{" ) too. The code i have is the following

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\node (p0) at ( -2.3,0.25) {};
\node (p1) at ( 0, 0) {}; 
\node (p2) at ( 0.8,-0.2) {$i$};
    \node (p3) at ( 2,0) {};
    \node (p4) at ( 0,0.6) {};
    \node (p5) at ( 1.8,0.8) {$j$};
\node (p6) at ( 2,0.6) {};

\node (p7) at ( 2.2,0.3) {$\cdot$}; 

\node (p8) at ( 2.4,0) {};  
\node (p9) at ( 3.5,-0.2) {$k$};  
\node (p10) at ( 4.4,0) {};  
\node (p11) at ( 2.4,0.6) {};  
\node (p12) at ( 2.8,0.8) {$l$};  
\node (p13) at ( 4.4,0.6) {};  

\node (p14) at (4.6,-0.3){=};

\begin{scope}
   \draw (p1) -- (p3); 
   \draw (p4) -- (p6);
   \draw [ shorten <=-0.08cm, shorten >=-0.15cm, -latex](p2) -- (p5);
   \draw (p8) -- (p10); 
   \draw (p11) -- (p13);
   \draw [ shorten <=-0.08cm, shorten >=-0.15cm, -latex](p9) -- (p12);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c l}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\node (p1) at ( 0, -1) {}; 
\node (p3) at ( 3,-1) {};
\node (p4) at ( 0,0) {};
\node (p6) at ( 3,0) {};
\node (p7) at ( 0,1) {};
\node (p9) at ( 3,1) {};
\node (p2) at ( 1, -1.2) {$i$};
\node (p5) at ( 2,0) {};
\node (p10)at (2.05,-0.2){};
\node (p8) at ( 1.5,1.2) {$l$};

\node (p11)at (3.3, 0){=};

\node (p12)at (3.6, -0.5){};
\node (p13)at (4.6, -0.7){$i$};
\node (p14)at (6.6, -0.5){};
\node (p15)at (3.6, 0.5){};
\node (p16)at (5.1, 0.7){$l$};
\node (p17)at (6.6, 0.5){};
\node (p18)at (7.5, 0){si j=k};
\begin{scope}
   \draw (p1) -- (p3); 
   \draw (p4) -- (p6);
   \draw (p7) -- (p9);
   \draw [ shorten <=-0.08cm, shorten >=-0.15cm, -latex](p2) -- (p5);
   \draw [ shorten <=0.02cm, shorten >=-0.10cm, -latex](p10) -- (p8);

   \draw (p12) -- (p14); 
   \draw (p15) -- (p17);
   \draw [shorten <=-0.08cm, shorten >=-0.1cm, -latex](p13) -- (p16);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
} \\
\\
0,$ \hspace{16mm} en otro caso$\\    
\\

\end{array}
\right.
$
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: And it shows this graphs:]

In conclusion what i want is the following: (i edited the image above to draw the desired diagram)

[image: Desired diagram]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that if you add `baseline=(current bounding box.center)` to your `tikzpicture` environments then they will be vertically centered around their midpoint with the result that your equation should be properly aligned.

[image]

In fact, with your example this does not quite work because you are typsetting this in an unusual way. First, displayed equations should be put inside either an `equation` environment or inside `\[...\]` (rather than inside a centered equation typset with `$...$`. Secondly, equations like this with multiple branches are better typset using the `cases` environment from the [amsmath](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package. Making these changes leads to the diagram above and the code looks like:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
  \node (p0) at ( -2.3,0.25) {};
  \node (p1) at ( 0, 0) {};
  \node (p2) at ( 0.8,-0.2) {$i$};
      \node (p3) at ( 2,0) {};
      \node (p4) at ( 0,0.6) {};
      \node (p5) at ( 1.8,0.8) {$j$};
  \node (p6) at ( 2,0.6) {};

  \node (p7) at ( 2.2,0.3) {$\cdot$};

  \node (p8) at ( 2.4,0) {};
  \node (p9) at ( 3.5,-0.2) {$k$};
  \node (p10) at ( 4.4,0) {};
  \node (p11) at ( 2.4,0.6) {};
  \node (p12) at ( 2.8,0.8) {$l$};
  \node (p13) at ( 4.4,0.6) {};

  \begin{scope}
     \draw (p1) -- (p3);
     \draw (p4) -- (p6);
     \draw [ shorten <=-0.08cm, shorten >=-0.15cm, -latex](p2) -- (p5);
     \draw (p8) -- (p10);
     \draw (p11) -- (p13);
     \draw [ shorten <=-0.08cm, shorten >=-0.15cm, -latex](p9) -- (p12);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
=\begin{cases}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[thick,baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
    \node (p1) at ( 0, -1) {};
    \node (p3) at ( 3,-1) {};
    \node (p4) at ( 0,0) {};
    \node (p6) at ( 3,0) {};
    \node (p7) at ( 0,1) {};
    \node (p9) at ( 3,1) {};
    \node (p2) at ( 1, -1.2) {$i$};
    \node (p5) at ( 2,0) {};
    \node (p10)at (2.05,-0.2){};
    \node (p8) at ( 1.5,1.2) {$l$};

    \node (p11)at (3.3, 0){=};

    \node (p12)at (3.6, -0.5){};
    \node (p13)at (4.6, -0.7){$i$};
    \node (p14)at (6.6, -0.5){};
    \node (p15)at (3.6, 0.5){};
    \node (p16)at (5.1, 0.7){$l$};
    \node (p17)at (6.6, 0.5){};
    %\node (p18)at (7.5, 0){si j=k};
    \begin{scope}
       \draw (p1) -- (p3);
       \draw (p4) -- (p6);
       \draw (p7) -- (p9);
       \draw [ shorten <=-0.08cm, shorten >=-0.15cm, -latex](p2) -- (p5);
       \draw [ shorten <=0.02cm, shorten >=-0.10cm, -latex](p10) -- (p8);

       \draw (p12) -- (p14);
       \draw (p15) -- (p17);
       \draw [shorten <=-0.08cm, shorten >=-0.1cm, -latex](p13) -- (p16);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture} &\text{si }j=k\\
  0,&\text{en otro caso}\\
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Finally, your use of `tikz` is really verbose and can be simplified a lot. Here is how I might do this. It turns out that using the current bounding to set the baseline no longer works so well because the labels gve the tikz environments some extra space "underneath" so I manually set the baseline using the coordinate `bl`.

```
\tikzset{baseline=(bl.base), draw/.append style={thick}}
\[ \begin{tikzpicture}
      \coordinate(bl) at (1,0.4);  % set baseline
      \draw(0,0)--+(2,0);
      \draw(0,1)--+(2,0);
      \draw[-latex](0.6,0)node[below]{$i$}--(1.6,1)node[above]{$j$};
      \node at (2.3,0.5){$\cdot$};
      \draw(2.6,0)--+(2,0);
      \draw(2.6,1)--+(2,0);
      \draw[-latex](4.2,0)node[below]{$k$}--(3.6,1)node[above]{$l$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  = \begin{cases}\space
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \coordinate(bl) at (1,0.9);  % set baseline
      \draw(0,0)--+(2,0);
      \draw(0,1)--+(2,0);
      \draw(0,2)--+(2,0);
      \draw[-latex](0.6,0)node[below]{$i$}--(1.6,1);
      \draw[-latex](1.6,1)--(1,2)node[above]{$l$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    =
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \coordinate(bl) at (1,0.4);  % set baseline
      \draw(0,0)--+(2,0);
      \draw(0,1)--+(2,0);
      \draw[-latex](0.6,0)node[below]{$i$}--(1,1)node[above]{$l$};
    \end{tikzpicture},
   &\text{si }j=k\\
  0,&\text{en otro caso}\\
\end{cases}
\]
```

The space between the lines is large than what you had so you may want to tweak this. I h ave also made the points `k` and `j` the same distance along their lines so that the first diagram in the cases environment is correct. This is what this code produces:

[image]